# How can I pass an anonymous type to a function?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, anonymous-types

I have tables with either many columns or a column with a large data set (XML doc), I need to load information from the table quickly (status info) into a class. I notices that Linq allows you to select columns as such...:

Using an anonymous type:

```
var query = (from name in some.Table
            select new { ColumnName = name.ColumnName });

MapEntToOb( query)
private void MapEntToObj( var query)          <------ doesn't work!
```

I want to call a routine to do stuff (mapping) using the query, but cannot pass it unlike the following...

```
LinqClass.Table query =  from name in some.Table
            select;

MapEntToObj( query)
...
private void MapEntToObj( LinqClass.Table query)
```

for now I'll move the mapping into local scope, but I would like to have a clean consistant design for all by data mapping.