# LINQ result set passing into other method

Tags: c#, linq

```
var result = datatable.AsEnumerable()
                  .GroupBy(row=>row.Field<DateTime>("Date"))
                  .Select(gr=>new 
                  {
                      Date = gr.Key,
                      Agents = gr.Select(x => new 
                      {
                          Id = x.Field<int>("ID"),
                          Agent = x.Field<string>("Agent")
                      })
                  });

    foreach (var res in result) {  
            var lstAgents= res.Agents;
    ImportSchedule(lstAgents);
}
```

how can i pass `lstAgents` in `ImportSchedule()` method. What type i define in `ImportSchedule`?

Comment: When you do 'Select(gr=>new ...' you are creating an anonymous type.  Here you could find an answer to your question:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6624811/how-to-pass-anonymous-types-as-parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't pass anonymous type into method, but you can make class or struct like this:

```
public class AgentDto
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string Agent {get; set;}
}
```

in this case you shuld make method ImportSchedule like this:

```
public void ImportSchedule(IEnumerable<AgentDto> agents)
```

also take your attention that you not pass the date into ImportSchedule, but you probably need to do it

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
public void ImportSchedule(dynamic agents) { }
```

But you should make a class for this, the reason being if the property `Id` is changed to `AgentId` then you will find out the error on the Run time.

For more info:

[Link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6624811/how-to-pass-anonymous-types-as-parameters)