# How to return dynamic entity in GetEnumerator<T>

Tags: c#, linq, dynamic, ienumerable, ienumerator

I have class implemented from `IEnumerable<T>` :

```
    public class MyList<T> : IEnumerable<T>
    {
        IQueryable Queryable;
        public MyList(IQueryable ts)
        {
            Queryable = ts;
        }
        public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
        {
            foreach (var item in Queryable)
            {
                yield return (T)item;
            }
        }

        IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
        {
            return GetEnumerator();
        }
    }
```

When I select some property from `IQuerable` and do `ToList()`, it works:

```
        IQueryable propertiesFromClasses = classesIQuerable.Select(a => a.Property);
        MyList<MyClass> classes = new MyList<MyClass>(propertiesFromClasses);
        var toListResult = classes.ToList();
```

Now, I want to select dynamic types:

```
        IQueryable propertiesFromClasses = classesIQuerable.Select(a => new { SelectedProperty = a.Property });
        MyList<MyClass> classes = new MyList<MyClass>(propertiesFromClasses);
        var toListResult = classes.ToList();
```

It throws exception in `yield return (T)item;` of `GetEnumerator()` method:

System.InvalidCastException: 'Unable to cast object of type '<>f__AnonymousType0`1[System.String]' to type 'MyClass'.'

Comment: Obviously you cannot cast anything else than a `MyClass` object to `MyClass` and you won't be able to specify the type parameter with an anonymous type. Please refer to @JaredPar's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/775402/7252182).

Comment: @mm8, But when I select property it works. And it isn't MyClass type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is obviously in the constructor of `MyClass<T>`.

### Make a proper constructor

First of all, if you want to implement a class `MyClass<Order>` that represents an enumerable sequence of `Order` objects, why do you allow a constructor that accepts `IQueryable<Student>`?

Wouldn't it be better to only accept a sequence of `Orders`, or at least a sequence of items that can be converted to `Orders`?

This way your compiler will complain, instead of later during execution of the code.

```
public class MyList<T> : IEnumerable<T>
{
    IQueryable<T> queryable;
    public MyList(IQueryable<T> ts)
    {
        this.queryable = ts;
    }
    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return this.Queryable;
    }
    ...
}
```

If you'd done this, your compiler would already have complained, instead of a run-time exception.

The object that you created in your 2nd piece of code is an object that implements `IQueryable<someAnonymousClass>`. Your debugger will tell you that this object does not implement `IQueryable<MyClass>`

Objects that implement `IQueryable<someAnonymousClass>` also implements `IQueryable`. However, elements that can be enumerated from this `IQueryable`, are of type `someAnonymousClass` those objects can't be cast to `MyClass` without a proper conversion method.

Your first piece of code does not lead to this problem, because the object that you created implements `IQueryable<MyClass>`, and thus the enumerator will yield `MyClass` objects, which can be converted to `MyClass` objects without problems.

But again: if you had made a proper constructor, you would have noticed the problem at compile time, instead of at run-time.

### Alternative solution

It could be that you really wanted to design a class that could hold a sequence of `Students` in and try to get extract all `Orders` from it, or a more realistic problem: put a sequence of `Animals` and enumerate all `Birds`. Such a class could extract all Birds from any sequence:

```
public class FilteredEnumerator<T> : IEnumerable<T>
{
    public FilteredEnumerator(IQueryable queryable)
    {
         this.queryable = queryable;
    }

    private readonly IQueryable queryable;

    private IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return this.queryable.OfType<T>();
    }
}
```

Although this would work. I'm not sure if it would be a very meaningful class. There is already a LINQ function that does what you want:

var birds = myDbContext.Animals.OfType();

Comment: You can not do  return this.Queryable; (in your first code) and also you can not do this.queryable.OfType<T>(); (in your second peace of code)

Comment: Whether you can use `IQueryable.OfType<...>()` or not depends on how smart your `IQueryable.Provider` is. According to [Supported and unsupported LINQ methods for Liq to entities] (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/ef/language-reference/supported-and-unsupported-linq-methods-linq-to-entities) this is one of the functions supported by entity framework