# Excluding types from generic object-type argument

Tags: c#, .net

I have an overloaded radio button extension method that is throwing the runtime execution off. The arguments of the first method can, in certain cases, be confused for the arguments of the second, and vice-versa.

```
public static MvcHtmlString MyRadioButton<TModel>( this HtmlHelper<TModel> helper, string property_name, string value, bool is_checked, string label = "", object attributes = null, bool separate_label = false, bool within_div = true, bool label_after = true )
        {
            // method implementation
        }
```

and the overload:

```
public static MvcHtmlString MyRadioButton<TModel>( this HtmlHelper<TModel> helper, string property_name, string value, bool is_checked, object attributes = null, bool separate_label = false, bool within_div = true, bool label_after = true )
        {
            return MyRadioButton(helper, property_name, value, is_checked, "", attributes, separate_label, within_div, label_after);
        }
```

In this case:

```
Html.MyRadioButton("name", "value", true, "");
```

the empty string is valid as both the object-type "attributes" argument **and** as the string-type "label" argument, causing a conflict between the methods.

Is there a way to generically type an argument and then exclude types from that definition in the method? I'm thinking maybe an inheritance class of the object type that accepts a list of types to exclude, like `object<string>`. The alternative solution is to jumble the arguments of the overload so it is apparent which needs to be called, but that's far less elegant than properly typing the arguments.

Comment: I think I may be looking for type constraints. I'll continue looking into this and answer the question if it turns out to solve the problem.

Comment: I'm not seeing how to get where I'm going with where T clauses, as there's no way to exclude types, from my searching. I may end up just using an AnonymousType for the parameters argument, since it is generally passed as `new { param: value }`

Comment: seems that anonymously-typed arguments aren't possible in C#
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6624811/how-to-pass-anonymous-types-as-parameters

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Beginning with "label" in the first and "attributes" in the second, each argument has a default value, so if no further args are supplied to the overload beyond "label", it can potentially pass the intended label as the "attributes" object in the overload.

Comment: Anonymous typed parameters are **certainly** possible C#. [Dapper](https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper), for example, uses them to create `SqlCommand` parameters. The challenge is controlling the shape of the anonymous type.

Comment: @ConnorLow I'm aware of object-typed arguments, but have not yet seen how an object structured `new { foo: bar }` can be required through a method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the empty string could be either a `string` or an `object` you can distinguish whether you want the empty string to be passed as the `label` or the `attributes` when you call by specifying the name:

```
Html.MyRadioButton("name", "value", true, label: "")
```

```
Html.MyRadioButton("name", "value", true, attributes: "")
```

Comment: Can't display my +1 yet, but I think this is the winning answer. No refactoring needed for type-specificity since this allows name-specificity to dominate. My question is perhaps only answerable as yes/no, with no being the answer given the circumstances of C#, so I'll let the proposal most **helpful**, in my opinion, have it. Thanks for the solve!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a simple solution like creating a special class of string can do the job better than using `generic type constraint`

**[UPDATED]**
Here is my suggestion:

```
public class MySpecialString
{
    public string MyStringl;
    public MySpecialString(string txt)
    {
        this.MyStringl = txt;
    }
}

public class MyAttributes
{
    public MyAttributes()
    {

    }
}

public static class Extentions
{
    public static MvcHtmlString MyRadioButton<TModel>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> helper, string property_name,
        string value, bool is_checked, MySpecialString mystring = null , object attributes = null, bool separate_label = false,
        bool within_div = true, bool label_after = true)
    {
        // method implementation
    }

    public static MvcHtmlString MyRadioButton<TModel>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> helper, string property_name,
        string value, bool is_checked, MyAttributes attributes = null, bool separate_label = false,
        bool within_div = true, bool label_after = true)
    {
        // method implementation
    }
}
```

Comment: The issue isn't that string isn't specific enough. MySpecialString will still satisfy the object-type "attributes" parameter if nothing further is supplied, since the following arguments are all supplied with defaults.

Comment: OK you are right, I have another solution I will update.

Comment: Now you can give a default value for each parameter, please see my update.

Answer (score 0):

Why the overload at all? Simply delegate inside one single method to the appropiate implementation defining a default value for `label` that allows you to discern what option the consumer wants.

```
public static MvcHtmlString MyRadioButton<TModel>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> helper,
                                                  string property_name,
                                                  string value,
                                                  bool is_checked,
                                                  string label = null, //general case
                                                  object attributes = null,
                                                  bool separate_label = false,
                                                  bool within_div = true,
                                                  bool label_after = true )
{
     if (label == null)
         return myImplentationWithLabelNotDefined( //all arguments//);

     return myImplementationWithLabelDefined(//all arguments//);
}
```

You can even define the helper methods as inner functions to avoid argument clutter...

Comment: The overload is meant to overcome the need to define "label" when no label is needed, as there are many cases in which you want to pass "attributes" but no "label". This is an imitation of the overloads present in the default Html RadioButton static method, so not something I came up with myself, unfortunately! haha

Comment: @LukeFaez Well, if its common you need attributes but not label, then switch those two around...

Answer (score 0):

If the `attributes` parameter is meant to be used for POCOs and not value types (e.g. never string, integer, boolean, etc.), you could do something like this:

```cs
public static MvcHtmlString MyRadioButton<TModel, T>( 
    this this HtmlHelper<TModel>, ...,
    T attributes,
    ... // omitted for brevity
) where T: new() // <- IMPORTANT LINE
{ 
    // etc...
}

// which can be used with any anonymous or structured object:
helper.MyRadioButton(new { attribute1 = "hello world" }); 
helper.MyRadioButton(new MyClass());

// but not value types:
helper.MyRadioButton("this won't work for the above overload");
```

I would hope adding a generic constraint would be enough for the runtime to "know better" if this matches your use-case.

---

If you **are** only using this for POCOs, I would add the constraint either way. Then you never have to worry about accidentally passing in a value type.

### UPDATE

> Is there a way to generically type an argument and then exclude types from that definition in the constructor?

I dodged this question in my original answer. Using the `where` constraint, you can restrict passed types to a type, but you cannot specify types to exclude. See *Type parameter constraints* [language specification](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/classes#type-parameter-constraints) and [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/where-generic-type-constraint) for more details.

Comment: I considered type constraints soon after posting and found them inadequate for purpose, but thanks for the input!