# the type of var (without using dynamics)?

Tags: c#, .net, anonymous-types, var

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I pass an anonymous type to a method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55101/how-can-i-pass-an-anonymous-type-to-a-method)

Im trying to recognize the type of the anonymous type.

```
List<int> lst = new List<int> {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};

var myVarType = from item in lst select new {P = item*item, P2 = item + "###"};

foreach (var k in myVarType)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(k.P + "     " + k.P2);
        }
```

[image]

Now i want a part of code to be transferred to a function but it screams that he doesnt know the type - which is logical since var is to be known at compile time and he doesnt know the type at compile :

[image]

I **dont** want to use dynamic || Tuples.

and as you know var is not acceptable as a func param type.

**But** , Ive once read that there is a `trick` which lets me transfer to `myFunc` the `anonymous type` .

I think it was by Jon skeet or Eric lippert.

Help ?

### edit

look at my self answer. 
I found it here
[What's the return type of an anonymous class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6466054/whats-the-return-type-of-an-anonymous-class/6469199#6469199)

Comment: The 'trick' is here I think: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2012/01/23/anonymous-types-unify-within-an-assembly.aspx

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/775387/passing-a-anonymous-type-to-function <- it pretty much states it's not possible

Comment: @henk I already read this its not the one. there is other code . I will try to find it and let you know

Comment: @HenkHolterman yeah thats the code. i found it here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6466054/whats-the-return-type-of-an-anonymous-class/6469199#6469199

Comment: @RoyiNamir But it won't let you access any property in a method. So your question is only going to work when casting the dynamic type before. Thats a big garbage.

Comment: @YngveB.Nilsen it is possible see the link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is the code which i found

[What's the return type of an anonymous class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6466054/whats-the-return-type-of-an-anonymous-class/6469199#6469199)

```
static T CastByExample<T>(object source, T example) where T : class
{
    return source as T;
}

static object ReturnsAnonymous() { return new { X = 123 }; }

static void DoIt()
{
    object obj = ReturnsAnonymous();
    var example = new { X = 0 };
    var anon = CastByExample(obj, example);
    Console.WriteLine(anon.X); // 123
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The type is 'generated' and you might be able to get it at run-time with reflection but it will contain characters you can't use in a name.

You could use Tuples:

```
 select new Tuple<int,string> ( item*item,  item + "###");
```

Comment: i know sorry I dont want tuples either.

Comment: cause im trying to learn here the trick

Comment: The trick is not a trick - it's a hack, and it's not the way it should be done.. You would be better off trying to rewrite the code in a way so that it follows standards and utilizes the tools the framework provides.

Comment: Yngve i dont want to use tuples since of item1 item2 ....

Answer (score 1):

Make the method generic, this should work.

```
static void MyFunc<T>(IEnumerable<T> myVarType) ...
```

#### Edit

As mentioned in comments you can't access the properties. You could use here a delegate to access the properties or use dynamic ( which you don't want to use ).

```
static void MyFunc<T>(IEnumerable<T> myVarType, Func<T, Object[]> argumentCreator)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", argumentCreator(myVarType));
}
```

Comment: no its not working either http://i.stack.imgur.com/PIefW.jpg

Comment: wont work, as the T is not properly resolved when you enter the method. It'll initially just be an object.. Only solution here is to use dynamic, but he doesn't want to do that.

Comment: @user1096188 Then you need dynamic.